# Is it possible to use ToString() value in class summary xml tag?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, string, summary

Is it possible to use ToString() in summary xml tag?

```
    /// <summary>
    /// I want to use the value from ToString() here.
    /// </summary>
    public class TheObject
    {
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "Hellow World!";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this about laziness? :D

Comment: :D, not exactly. My team members will forget to change the text on both locations 100%. :)

Comment: @mynkow: Making ToString return the documentation of your class seems like a pretty strange thing to do.

Comment: @mynkow oh, ok, change "laziness" with... *is about forgetful team members?* :)

Comment: Well, it is only for command and event classes in cqrs application.

Comment: @Matías Fidemraizer: Man, u made my day :) LOL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

These are [*comments*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx), not executable code.

Comment: What about the reverse. Use the text from xml comment in ToString() method.

Comment: @mynkow: Possible under certain circumstances and a bit complex. You basically will need to deliver the generated XML-doc file with your assembly and parse it at runtime to find the correct entry.

Comment: Ok, So I can do this with the release script. 10x

Answer (score 0):

You *may be* can do something like this using AOP (Aspect Oriented Programming).

But as this ia bout a *comments*, I personally, don't see any sence of defining a "dynamic" comment like this (I suppose, if string changes, you would like that comment changes too). Comments has to be basic description of the functionality, without need of diging into the *concrete* implementation details and values of the code inside the artifact it describes.